# Checkbox marcada automaticamente em array

Tags: php, html, checkbox

Estou quebrando a cabeça para definir uma checkbox como marcada.

Eu conheço s sintaxe da marcação (`<input checked>`) porém essa checkbox em particular esta sendo montada a partir de um array e eu não consegui, e nem sei se é possível, definir como *checked*.

Esse é o código:

```
array(
            'form_id'      => 'global_settings',
            'id'           => 'enable_public_questions',
            'element'      => ($settings['enable_public_questions']) ? 'checkbox' : false, 
            'label'        => $this->_('Accept Public Questions'),
            'description'  => $this->_('Check the above checkbox to allow site users to post public questions .'),
            'multiOptions' => array(
                1 => null,
            ),
        ),
        array(
```

Acredito que essa parte seja responsável pela exibição:

```
<global_settings>
    <label>Global Settings</label>
    <module>members</module>
    <controller>tools</controller>
    <action>global-settings</action>
    <resource>Tools</resource>
    <privilege>GlobalSettings</privilege>
</global_settings>
```

achei mais uma parte:

```
class Checkbox extends Element
{

    /**
     *
     * type of element - override the variable from the parent class
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_element = 'checkbox';

public function render()
    {
        $output = null;
        $value = $this->getValue();

        $multiple = '';
        if (count((array) $this->_multiOptions) > 1 || $this->getMultiple() === true) {
            $multiple = $this->_brackets;
        }


        $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->_name . $multiple . '" value=""'
                . $this->_endTag;

        foreach ((array) $this->_multiOptions as $key => $option) {
            $checked = (in_array($key, (array) $value)) ? ' checked="checked" ' : '';

            if (is_array($option)) {
                $title = $option[0];
                $description = $option[1];
            }
            else {
                $title = $option;
                $description = null;
            }
            $output .= '<label class="checkbox">'
                    . '<input type="' . $this->_element . '" name="' . $this->_name . $multiple . '" value="' . $key . '" '
                    . $this->renderAttributes()
                    . $checked
                    . $this->_endTag
                    . ' ' . $title
                    . ((!empty($description)) ? '<span class="help-block">' . $description . '</span>' : '')
                    . '</label>'
                    . "\n";
        }

        return $output;
    }

}
```

Comment: Marko, como está a converter isso para HTML?

Comment: Ai é que esta, a única parte responsável por esse campo que encontrei foi nessa página em que esta array. Tentei pesquisar nas outras páginal por algum chamado da array: 'id'           => 'enable_public_questions', mas não encontrei em nenhuma página

Comment: Um pouco mais abaixo da página encontrei o chamado que monta a array  return $array;   }

Comment: Existe um `echo` algures que envia isso para o lado do cliente?

Comment: `foreach ((array) $this->_multiOptions as $key => $option) {
            $checked = (in_array($key, (array) $value)) ? ' checked="checked" ' : '';` a parte responsável por marcar como `checked` é esta aí, mas ainda assim não se consegue fazer muito, porque `$value` recebe valores de uma outra função `getValue`, e nessa parte do teu código não dá para ver essa função. Mas é basicamente isto, ela marca como `checked` os valores provenientes de `getValue` que estiverem na array `multiOptions`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Já resolvi, tive que adaptar uma função que quando o campo nao estava selecionado dava um return false, mudei para return true, e mesmo sem checar o campo o problema foi resolvido. Era o que eu precisa, porem a questão de definir como checked na array fica um mistério.

Agradeço a todos que se dispuseram a me ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Experimenta adicionar:

```
'values' => true,
```

ou

```
'values' => array('value',true),
```

Em algumas configurações de php com xml é assim.

Comment: eu acrescentei, porem não surtiu efeito 'values' => true, e 'values' => array('value',true), no php mas continua sem ficar checado.